# How can I get in one spesific folder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have made clean urls in .htaccess file, but after that I dont get Access to a spesific folder. How can I get Access to /folder/?

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?side=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?side=$1 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/?$ index.php?side=$1&id=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^rss/feed/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/?$ index.php?side=feed&id=$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
##-if an existent dir or file is requested, serve it immideatly##    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
########    

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?side=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?side=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^rss/feed/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/?$ index.php?side=feed&id=$1 [NC,L]
```